# What is the most efficient way to cleanup test databases in between tests?

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, integration-testing

Considering the following setup:

- Springboot
- Any non-in-memory database
- Usage of `@Sql` annotation to add initial data for a test
- No DBUnit (great lib, but discontinued)
- Non transactional tests

I would like to get some generic code to truncate all tables which has been affected by some query, starting from before the `@Sql` annotation inserts the data and ending after the test is over (or any `@Sql` annotation that runs after the test has finished).

I can't use any hibernate/jpa related events (since the `@Sql` annotation does not rely on hibernate).

I saw some solution online which uses the `Datasource` to get the db catalog and truncate all the tables (of course it is possible to add some list of tables to skip or include), but I guess that would be a sub-optimal solution.

I tried to look indo Debezium embedded, but it looks like a bit too much for what I need to do and also it requires me to upgrade too many libs.

I can use the `JdbcUtils` provided with spring to truncate a list of tables which I can provide, but this has some drawbacks, for instance if some new code which affects another table is added, I might forget to add that table in the list. Also I need to consider all possible side effects that happen in the code and track down all the affected tables.

What I imagine is some kind of Proxy or Listener at some JDBC level, which would provide me the queries that are ran every time and I can extract the tables from there manipulating the string. Even better if there is some structure which provides me some structured data of what happened.

Some third party lib can be considered, but only if it is still supported.

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software) See it’s [`clean`](https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/commands/clean) command.

Comment: @BasilBourque this would drop the entire db and recreate every test, it would be very inefficient